# how to access function or variable in class or activity from androidmanifest?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob

is it possible to replace the value of `@string/AdMob_app_id` with a function or variable from another class or activity?

Currently the *admob app id* value comes from a string and I want to change the source, for example I get the *Admob Id* from the parsing API or from the SharedPreference that I have saved.

How to?

[image: Androidmanifest]

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
   android:value="@string/AdMob_app_id" />
<meta-data
   android:name="com.startapp.sdk.APPLICATION_ID"
   android:value="@string/app_id_start.io" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It’s not possible. Values in the manifest are constants that are readable by the OS (or storefronts) without launching and running any code in your app.

AdMob IDs are locked to your package name anyway. There’s no practical reason for it to not be a constant.